# Rails error when starting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting with rails and I'm having the following error when starting the server.

```
$ rails s
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/tracelines19.rb:12:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)
Referenced from: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.bundle - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.bundle
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/tracelines19.rb:12:in `rescue in <module:TraceLineNumbers>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/tracelines19.rb:8:in `<module:TraceLineNumbers>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/tracelines19.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/linecache19.rb:69:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/lib/linecache19.rb:69:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /Users/Crysfel/Sites/rails/quizzpot/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm using:

Rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3p194

Here's my config/application.rb file:

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

    # Pick the frameworks you want:
    require "active_record/railtie"
    require "action_controller/railtie"
    require "action_mailer/railtie"
    require "active_resource/railtie"
    require "sprockets/railtie"
    # require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

    if defined?(Bundler)
      # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
      Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
      # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
      # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
    end

    module Quizzpot
      class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    # config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

Comment: Please attach an `/Users/Crysfel/Sites/rails/quizzpot/config/application.rb` code.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your help. I've updated the original post with the application.rb file. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shows you are having a problem with the `linecache19` gem. A Google search shows that others have encountered the same problem: it seems to be an incompatibility between that gem and Ruby 1.9.3.

Is `linecache19` in your Gemfile? If so, can you just remove it? (Do you really need it?) If it's not in the Gemfile, look in Gemfile.lock and see if it's listed as a dependency of one of your other gems.

Comment: Thank you, I've removed that gem from my Gemfile and my applications is working fine.